# How to create ggplot with 2 variables?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

My data looks like this:

```
df <- structure(list(`Recorded ID` = c(6L, 7L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
16L, 17L, 18L), Initial = c(2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 22L, 4L, 0L, 9L, 
16L, 20L), Final = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 19L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 20L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

I am trying to make a plot that is similar to [image: this]

EXCEPT only change would be is that City on that plot would be "Record ID" from my data. I am having a lot of trouble if someone could help me thank you so much!

I have tried many things but none have helped

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a Grouped Bar Plot with Ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55717520/creating-a-grouped-bar-plot-with-ggplot)

Answer (score 1):

This is a `bar plot` which can be accomplished using `geom_bar`:

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(-`Recorded ID`, names_to = 'Key')%>%
  mutate(Recorded.ID = factor(`Recorded ID`))%>%
  ggplot(aes(y = Recorded.ID, x = value, fill = Key) ) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge')
```

[image]

Comment: If you use `geom_col()` you can skip the `stat = "identity"` argument

Comment: @JohanRosa yes, thats right. Though for newbies, its not straightforward to connect `geom_col` to barplots

Comment: You're right, good point of view.

Comment: Thank you all so much!! Yes I am a newbie so I am slowly learning things I really appreciate all your help :)